# Callback hell on my Nodejs webservice sending to elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, callback

I have a NodeJs consumer sending data to Elasticsearch at a rate of 2k TPS more or less. 
I need to store the Requests as I receive them, and if there is any response, later on, I need to update the info on the request with some data from the response. The thing is that due to the hight TPS, I'm having a lot of issues where the response arrives in Elasticsearch before the request etc.. and this creates a Version conflict on the _doc.  this is the part of my node code that does the upsert. I need some help to optimizing this code. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
 sendToElasticSearch(index, type, id, body, cb) {
    out('starting sendToElasticSearch()');
    var me = this;
    me.client.exists({
        index: index,
        type: type,
        id: id
    }, function(err, exists) {
        if (err) {
            cb(err)
        } else {
            if (exists === true) {
                out('exists. doing update.');
                // update existing document
                me.client.update({
                    index: index,
                    type: type,
                    id: id,
                    body: body

                }, function(err, resp) {
                    if (err) {
                        cb(err);
                    } else {
                        cb(null, resp);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                out('adding new document');
                // add new document
                me.client.create({
                    index: index,
                    type: type,
                    id: id,
                    body: body
                }, function(err, resp) {
                    if (err) {
                        cb(err);
                    } else {
                        cb(null, resp);
                    }
                });
            }
       }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sendToElasticSearch(index, type, id, body, cb) {
    var self = this;

    function onDone (err, exists) {
        if (err) 
            return cb(err); 

        var do = exists ? 'update' : 'create';
        self[do]({index, type, id, body}, cb);  
    }

    self.client.exists({index, type, id}, onDone);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast response Aikon, I update the code and now im receiving an "Unexpected token (do)" on the 'do' variable.

Comment: Change `do` to another name e.g. `action`. I don't know that `do` is reserved word.